# Unable to launch an application in chrome browser using coded ui

Tags: selenium, cross-browser, selenium-chromedriver, coded-ui-tests

I have a hand written coded ui test. It is working well with IE but I want to run in chrome. I have installed the Cross Browser Selenium components with the chromedriver (2.45). After the installation I have changed my code with BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome"; line. Actually it launches the chrome (71.0.3578.98) but then it fails with this exception :

"**Initialize threw exception. System.ArgumentNullException:System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Paramaeter name : windowHandle**"

Can anyone help me out!

Comment: To get helpful answers, please also provide the code that gives you this error.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Unit Test Project with all Selenium and Browser Drivers.

That should do the trick!

Hope this helps you!